# What is the most efficient way to manipulate a 2D dynamic array of std::strings in memory?

Tags: c++, string, vector

I currently use
 
`std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > MyStringArray` 
But I have read several comments here on SO that discourage the use of nested vectors on efficiency grounds.
Unforunately I have yet to see examples of alternatives to nested vector for a situation like this.

Comment: Why are you building a 2D dynamic array of std::strings? Tell us more about the nature of your data; this structure is efficient at certain uses, but less efficient for others.

Comment: What is dynamic, exactly? Do the array's dimensions change once it's created, or do they stay the same?

Comment: What do you mean by "manipulate"? How and how often you modify the data? How and how often you read it?

Comment: @bdonlan The most common situation is when the data is coming from a database. The rows are columns of strings ( there are some are other data types but cast them to string anyway for ease of display )

Comment: The rows are columns...? You mean it's in column-major order? What kind of manipulations are you going to do with this data?

Comment: @LaC The dimensions don't change once created but they are not known at compile time

Comment: @bdonlan. 'Manipulation' is mostly read ( indexing into ) cell contents v[x][y]

Comment: A simple solution is to use a plain vector and access each element as `x * N + y`, where `N` is the number of columns in your DB table. You can then grow this vector dynamically by inserting multiples of `N` strings as needed.

Comment: Normally, you read information from databases by row. You read a row from a query, process it, then read another row from the query. You generally don't load every single row at once. And for good reason.

Comment: @Kerrek SB I have seen suggestions along this line but clearly I have no idea how I could implement it. Do you care to answer my question with example code?

Comment: There isn't anything wrong about it, if that's what you need. I can easily imagine an object holding a vector of lists, where a list is a vector of strings.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas Think of a situation where you want to maintain a local cache of the resultset and be able to scroll back and forward through the local cache

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple dynamic 2D array with runtime-configurable column number:

```
class TwoDArray
{
  size_t NCols;
  std::vector<std::string> data;

public:
  explicit TwoDArray(size_t n) : NCols(n) { }

  std::string & operator()(size_t i, size_t j) { return data[i * NCols + j]; }
  const std::string & operator()(size_t i, size_t j) const { return data[i * NCols + j]; }

  void set_number_of_rows(size_t r) { data.resize(NCols * r); }

  void add_row(const std::vector<std::string> & row)
  {
    assert(row.size() == NCols);
    data.insert(data.end(), row.begin(), row.end());
  }
};
```

Usage:

```
TwoDArray arr(5); // five columns per row
arr.set_number_of_rows(20);
arr(0, 3) = "hello";
arr(17,2) = "world";
```

This is just a completely arbitrary and random example. Your real class would obviously have to contain interface methods that are suitable to what you're doing; or you might decide not to have a wrapping class at all and address the naked vector directly.

The key feature is the two-dimensional accessor operator via `(i,j)`, which replaces the nested vectors' `[i][j]`.

Comment: This looks promising. Let me do some tests. I assume NCold was a typo, you meant Nicols. Also the add_row function is referencing v instead of row?

Answer (score 1):

It seems a reasonable design to me, given your stated design goals. Note that you should avoid operations which resize the outer vector; these may result in a deep copy of all the data in the overall structure (this may be mitigated somewhat with a C++0x STL implementation).

Comment: This would also be mitigated by so-called "swaptimization", where swap-able types in vectors can be swapped rather than copied. It's basically move construction before move construction existed. VC++ 2008's STL implementation used this trick.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficent way is probably to have the strings be *contiguous in memory* (separated by null terminators), and having *contiguous* array of references to each string, and another *contiguous* array of references to each array.

This is to maintain locality and help use the cache effectively, but it really ultimately depends on how you access the data.